# How to use dojo.number.round to achieve toFixed functionality for whole numbers?

Tags: javascript, dojo, floating-point

Hi I reading about the usage of dojo.number.round to overcome the shortcomings of Javascript's toFixed() function: For ex/ In IE: (0.9).toFixed(1) yields “0.0” All other browsers: (0.9).toFixed(1) yields “1.0”, and this works great for non-whole numbers. However I have been able to successfully use (4).toFixed(2) to achieve an output with 2 decimal numbers of '4.00' but when trying to execute dojo.number.round(4,2) I just get '4', any suggestions on how to get the desired decimal point behavior of '4.00'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var n = dojo.number.round(4,2);
console.debug(dojo.number.format(n, {pattern:"0.00"}));
```